# Does the Admob network punish me in any way if I have a low "show rate"?

Tags: android, ios, admob

I use the strategy of preloading interstitials and rewarded videos at application startup, and this means that the user doesn't have to wait for an ad to load when it's time to display it. However, this also causes many ads that were requested to the admob network to not be displayed (because it was not the user's will or the time did not come), resulting in a low "show rate".
I've seen people saying that Admob can penalize profits if the "show rate" is low, but I haven't seen it anywhere making that clear

Answer (score 1):

No you wont be penalized for low flow rate. However, i am on a 30 day suspension with admob for having to many ads displayed. It is called invalid clicking. So if you have your app show ads continuously without the user consent or point of interest you can get a suspension for displaying to many ads.

If they punished you for having to low of ads then no one would ever use them. Too many ads will get you in trouble.

[image]